# Word selector box like chrome control G feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, box

I'm searching this answer on stack for several days with no results, so many results that don't ask the same i want to do. I'm trying to add a search box that select words in a html with a lot of text. In chrome you can do this with control+G keys or control+F in safari. It must be easy but i can't find the answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found in Site Point 10 free plugins to make this and i implemented to my site. without php and mysql.